# Optimize sampling on band 1 of a big dataset

Tags: python, rasterio, sampling

We do MANY samplings on band 1 of a big dataset, using rasterio dataset.sample function. (https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/sample.py)

Our python code looks something like this:

```
xy_list = [(448758.24921202223, 6239730.062386721)] # normally many more
with rasterio.open(tif_file_path) as dataset:
  sample_result_tuple = list(dataset.sample(xy = xy_list , indexes = 1))
  ...
```

Is there any way to speed this up, maybe by using some sort of fancy indexing or preprocessing? Any suggestion at all is welcome, even if it is not in python.

Answer (score 1):

3 ideas in order of least to most effort:

1. Ensure your TIFF is using internal tiling, which can be better for random reads.  `gdalinfo` can tell you about the structure if you're not sure if it's currently tiled or striped.  You can write a tiled tiff using the [gtiff driver's creation option](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options) `TILED=YES`.  You might want to benchmark this since I'm not sure how much it would actually gain you.
2. Use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to sample batches of points in parallel then recombine the results
3. Re-tile your single large image into many smaller files.  Index the bounds of these files with an [rtree](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree).  Query the rtree to determine which points fall into which file, then sample the files in parallel as in #2.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and see how it goes.